# Whether or not use max TTL for Redis?

Tags: memory, redis

I use Redis as cache solution for Wordpress. I set max memory at 128m. Why is max TLL used? And how can I understand if I should set a max TTL?

Comment: I'm sure anything about **max TTL**. Do you want to know about `maxmemory` or TTL?

Comment: I set max TTL at 604800 (a week) but I don't know why I picked this value. How can I find an optimum value looking at redis stats like memory etc. Regarding maxmemory, I set it at 128M as developers suggest so. My wordpress max memory is also 128mb, it is problem or related?

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant to say "I'm **not sure** anything about max TTL." And both of your questions are really subjective and the answers completely depend on the usage. I guess you'd have monitor regularly. If 128mb is able to server your general purpose, go ahead. And if Redis memory gets filled up or close to fill up frequently, you can try reducing TTL.

Comment: Which stat should I monitor? There are many memory related stats like used_memory, used_memory_rss, used_memory_peak, etc.

Comment: used_memory / used_memory_human